# Finding and replacing symbol in sas data step

Tags: sas

I have data set. In every observation it could has for ex. symbol "YY" So I need to replace it on "Y". How to do it in SAS data step? Thank you!

Comment: You may need further explanation as what you've included doesn't really explain much.  How about an input and an output example?  I've given some info on what you could possibly use and 2 methods on doing it.

Comment: @AmitPatel thanks! Problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the tranwrd function.

So:

```
data DS1;
infile cards dlm=",";
input var1:$2. var2:$10.;
cards;
YY, PRETTY
XX, EXCELLENT
ZZ, CODEZ
;
run;

data NEW;
set DS1;
  NEW_VAR1 = tranwrd(VAR1,"Y","A");
  NEW_VAR2 = tranwrd(VAR2, substr(VAR1,1,1), "GG");
run;
```